# Cannot install Anaconda on Linux

Tags: linux, anaconda

first, I tried command

```
 ./Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

and it reports that

```
/data/keeling/a/xinyix3/miniconda/pkgs/python-3.6.0-0/bin/python:
cannot execute binary file ERROR: cannot execute native osx-64 binary,
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux keeling.earth.illinois.edu
2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 12 11:25:51 
CDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am really new to Linux. Is there any suggestions of failure of installation?

Comment: Why does your `uname` say you're on linux if you're on a Mac/OSX? Are you running linux on a Mac?

Comment: Probably ssh'ed from their mac into a linux system

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be running the wrong binary/script for Miniconda. Use the [Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh](https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh) script if you're on linux, not the OSX one.

Comment: It works  ! Thank you so much! I really appreciate that!

Comment: @StellaXu If it works for you, please mark the answer as accepted, the protocol to follow is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers